# Work around to implement lag(ignore null) in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, lag, window-functions

I have the following sample table:

```
EmpID     | Type | timestamp           | block_id
----------------------------------------------------
    1     |  'R' | 2018-04-15 01:13:15 | AB12D
    1     |  'P' | 2018-04-15 05:13:15
    1     |  'P' | 2018-04-15 05:13:15
    1     |  'P' | 2018-04-15 05:13:15
    1     |  'D' | 2018-04-15 07:13:15
    1     |  'D' | 2018-04-15 08:13:15
    1     |  'D' | 2018-04-15 10:13:15
    1     |  'R' | 2018-04-15 13:13:00 | 1X1#1
    1     |  'P' | 2018-04-15 13:15:15
    1     |  'P' | 2018-04-15 13:15:15
    1     |  'P' | 2018-04-15 13:15:15
    1     |  'D' | 2018-04-15 14:13:00
    1     |  'D' | 2018-04-15 15:13:00
    1     |  'D' | 2018-04-15 16:13:37
    2     |  'R' | 2018-04-15 04:15:00 | __08XA
    2     |  'P' | 2018-04-15 04:20:00
    2     |  'D' | 2018-04-15 05:11:33
```

The table is not ordered as shown above and is just for explanation purposes. I want to know if there is a way to implement lag(ignore null) in Postgres SQL.

I want the following output:

```
EmpID     | Type | timestamp           | new_block_id
----------------------------------------------------
    1     |  'R' | 2018-04-15 01:13:15 | AB12D
    1     |  'P' | 2018-04-15 05:13:15 | AB12D
    1     |  'P' | 2018-04-15 05:13:15 | AB12D
    1     |  'P' | 2018-04-15 05:13:15 | AB12D
    1     |  'D' | 2018-04-15 07:13:15 | AB12D
    1     |  'D' | 2018-04-15 08:13:15 | AB12D
    1     |  'D' | 2018-04-15 10:13:15 | AB12D
    1     |  'R' | 2018-04-15 13:13:00 | 1X1#1
    1     |  'P' | 2018-04-15 13:15:15 | 1X1#1
    1     |  'P' | 2018-04-15 13:15:15 | 1X1#1
    1     |  'P' | 2018-04-15 13:15:15 | 1X1#1
    1     |  'D' | 2018-04-15 14:13:00 | 1X1#1
    1     |  'D' | 2018-04-15 15:13:00 | 1X1#1
    1     |  'D' | 2018-04-15 16:13:37 | 1X1#1
    2     |  'R' | 2018-04-15 04:15:00 | __08XA
    2     |  'P' | 2018-04-15 04:20:00 | __08XA
    2     |  'D' | 2018-04-15 05:11:33 | __08XA
```

So, these are sort of blocks for each EmpID. i.e., these are sort of blocks and each empId can have multiple blocks. So from the above sample table, empID '1' has 2 blocks (beginning from row 1 to row 7), and 2nd block from row 8 to row 14; empID 2 has 1 block, row 14 to row 16.

So, for a particular EmpID, ordered by timestamp, the top row that has a `block_id` value, that value should be filled in the `new_block_id` field for that block and so on.

I know postgres doesn't allow ignore null but is there a workaround to implement that for my case? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm using Redshift and it uses Postgresql

Comment: Redshift doesn't "use" Postgres. It's a fork of a very old Postgres version.

Answer (score 1):

Use a running sum to define groups and get the `max` value of that group.

```
select empid,type,timestamp,max(block_id) over(partition by empid,grp order by timestamp) as block_id
from (select t.*
      ,sum(case when block_id is null then 0 else 1 end) over(partition by empid order by timestamp) as grp
      from tbl t
     ) t
```

Edit: [Demo which works](http://rextester.com/SJXD24133)

Comment: This does not work. It only fills the rows which already have block_id value.

Comment: have you tried the query yet? it should definitely work.

Comment: Yes I tried it and that's what it returns. BTW I needed to add "rows between unbounded preceding and current row" to your aggregate window functions as well.

Comment: included a demo which shows it works on the data shown here atleast

Answer (score 1):

you probably need `last_value(block_id ignore nulls) over (partition by emp_id order by "timestamp" rows between unbounded preceding and current row)`

Comment: thanks for the answer. This perfectly satisfies the question.

Answer (score 0):

Vamsi Prabhala's methods should works, let me explain it in detail logic.

1. You need use a 0/1 column to indicate the Null/Non-Null data
2. Then create accumulate summary column to calculate the indicator number in step 1.
   -now you can see the data already looks like grouped by your non_Null data.
3. As last step, pls use a Max function group by the accumulate sum (in step 2) to populate the data(here is block_id) in to empty items.

---

[image: Methods Logic example]